# Why aren't axis titles and labels showing up in base R when using plot()?

Tags: r

I'm trying to run `plot()`, and I can't get the default axis labels or titles to show up on either the x or y axes. The last time I ran this code, it worked just fine. Both R and R Studio have been updated within the last month, and I've tried closing and restarting R Studio. I have the same issue with both my own data and built in data, such as the iris data set. As you can see, without repressing the axis labels and titles, no axis labels and titles are added to the plot of sepal length by species.

```
plot(iris$Species, iris$Sepal.Length)
```

[image]

I think not seeing axis labels and titles is a symptom of a larger issue, as I'm also having difficulty adding any labels or titles using commands like `title(ylab="Sepal Length", line=2.5, cex.lab=1, family = "Calibri Light")`. Either the code runs without error and no label appears (if I don't specify font family), or I get an error message `font family not found`. I've tried adding the `extrafonts` package and using fonts that I know are installed in that package, but I get this error regardless. It seems there's something preventing me from adding any text to base R plots. Any insights would be much appreciated.

Comment: ?? When I type in your code, I get axis labels.  What happens if you run your `title` statement without the font specification?

Comment: What about `plot(0:1,0:1); text(0.5,0.5,"hello")` ? is that also blank?

Comment: When I run the ``title`` command without a font specification, the code runs without error, but no title appears. When I run ``plot(0:1,0:1); text(0.5,0.5,"hello")`` I do see "hello" printed in the center of the figure. Good idea- now I know that not all text is blocked, just axis titles and labels.

Comment: I'm aware that my system is not behaving the same as yours will when it runs the code I've provided. I'm trying to figure out why and how to fix it.

Comment: One further comment: I only had this issue after switching to the AGG graphics backend as recommended by RStudio in a recent blog post. If you did that as well - try switching back to Windows as the backend. That solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've encountered this before and I think it is just a bug in R studio. Click the button that says clear all plots (the little broomstick) and it should perform as expected with the sample data.

Comment: Thanks - That actually didn't work for me. But I did confirm that this is an RStudio bug.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks - I was having the same issue but the "broomstick" did not work for me.

But I did confirm that this seems to be RStudio issue as when I output to a different graphics device the text is there.

Here's the MWE that I was trying:

```
library(extrafont)
#font_import(pattern = 'calibri')

#Works fine
dev.off()
plot(1,1)
text(1, 1, "Hello World", pos = 1)

# Specify Calibri through par
dev.off()
par(family = fonts()[1])
plot(1,1)
text(1, 1, "Hello World", pos = 1)
# No text, no axes
text(1, 1, "Hello World", pos = 1)
# a second call is not a solution
text(1, 1, "Hello World", pos = 1, cex = 0.7)
# is cex a solution - still no axes
axis(1, cex = 5) #not printing regardless of cex 
mtext(1, text = 'Hello World') #and mtext doesn't print either
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem on `Mac OS 11.2.1`; `R 4.0.3`
Restarting R Session within RStudio did not solve it.
Shutting down Rstudio and restarting did not solve it.
Launching the actual R application did not solve it.
I finally did a Restart of my machine, and then everything works fine.

I originally ran into the problem after I used `dev.copy(png, file="xxx.png"); dev.off()`
But now of course this works fine.
So some more information, but I don't think it will ultimately "solve" the issue. Sorry.